# How to send push notification to 2 devices without creating topic or group using just the FCM tokens in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I just need to send push notifications to a handful of devices. I have their device tokens in an array. Do I need to create topics or groups for this?

I can send push notifications individually using a for loop, but is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: Please do not mark this question as duplicate without understanding. The question

[FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) Send to multiple devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547277/fcm-firebase-cloud-messaging-send-to-multiple-devices)

has answers to use FCM Token  and groups, which I have clearly stated that is not my requirement. As far as 'registration_ids'  mentioned by other question is concerned its not mentioned anywhere in the official docs , if it is mentioned then please point it out as a valid answer.

Comment: what is your need? you need to send the messages to your  FCM tokens devices or your client mobile need to subscribe the topic. and you send  the messages based on topics.?

Comment: @user3026347 the first one of your comment

Comment: follow this URL https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Comment: Check this box for further references :  Downstream HTTP messages (JSON) registration_ids

Comment: check this URL Also https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#format

Comment: Hi I dont see any mention of registration_ids in the doc, it says the registration_ids is now replaced by the "to" field.

Answer (score 6):

Use "registration_ids" instead of "to".

```
var message = { 
    registration_ids:['id1','id2','id3'],
    notification: {
        title: 'Hello There...!', 
        body: 'this is test notification' 
    }
};
```

Hope It Works..!!!

Comment: Is there a documentation for this in firebase?

Comment: @Utsav Gupta you can use it from server side. check it out

Comment: it says "There is no support for multiple recipients."

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered and not a very latest question.

Sure, you can construct the `string array` and send it like this as mentioned in the google documentation [find here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group).

**HTTP POST request**

For example, to add a device with the registration ID 51 to appUser-Chris, you would send this request:

```
{
   "operation": "add",
   "notification_key_name": "appUser-Chris",
   "notification_key": "APA91bGHXQBB...9QgnYOEURwm0I3lmyqzk2TXQ",
   "registration_ids": ["51"] //you can insert something more of your strings here.
}
```

**Response format**

A successful request to either add or remove a device returns a notification_key like the following:

```
{
   "notification_key": "APA91bGHXQBB...9QgnYOEURwm0I3lmyqzk2TXQ"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Your code here!
class FCM
{
    private $key;

    function __construct($api_key)
    {
        $this->key = $api_key;
    }

    /**
     * Sending Push Notification
     */
    public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $notification)
    {
        $fields = array ( 'to' => $registatoin_ids,'notification' => $notification); //'restricted_package_name' => "com.apps.firebasenotificationphp");
        
        $headers = array (
                'Authorization: key=' . $this->key,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

       $ch = curl_init ();
       curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send" );
       curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
       curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
       curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
       curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields) );
       return curl_exec ( $ch );
       curl_close ( $ch );
    }
}

$api_key = "";
$device_id = "";
$fcm = new FCM($api_key);
$arrNotification = array ("body" => "hii","title" => "hello",'image' => "https://www.gstatic.com/devrel-devsite/prod/vb1c70bbe2f68b543db3deb1075af42e62f8f21e5fc703b8398dc6b9860f1711f/firebase/images/lockup.png",'link' => "",'sound' => "default");

echo $fcm->send_notification($device_id,$arrNotification);
?>
```